Magento 2: Nginx Rewrite Rule for Updated Media Base URL
I recently updated my media base URL to {{unsecure_base_url}}media/version1234567/. While attempting to create a rewrite rule in Nginx, I've encountered some difficulties.
For a single URL, I used the following configuration which works as expected:
location = /media/version1234567/wysiwyg/banners/WebsiteBanners2/HomePageBanners/Snom_Web_May_HP.png {
    return 301 http://voip.local/media/wysiwyg/banners/WebsiteBanners2/HomePageBanners/Snom_Web_May_HP.png;
}

However, for handling multiple URLs, I tried the following rule but it doesn’t seem to be working correctly:
location /media/ {
    rewrite ^/media/version\d+/(.*)$ /media/$1 break;
}

Despite my efforts, the rewrite rule for multiple URLs isn't functioning as intended. Could you please provide guidance or assistance on how to implement a rewrite rule that effectively handles all URLs with the version number?
Thank you for your help.

After further adjustments, I found a solution that works:
location /media/ {
    location ~ ^/media/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/media/version\d*/(.*)$ /media/$1 last;
    }
}

This configuration successfully handles the rewrite for multiple URLs by nesting the rewrite rule within the /media/ location block.
Best regards,

The rule for this kind of redirects already exists on the example repository. If you check the "Configure Nginx" inside https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/web-server/nginx you will see that they reference the nginx.conf.sample.
In that file you have the following configuration inside the static folder which can be mapped into the media folder: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/nginx.conf.sample#L106
Should be something similar to
location /media/ {

    location ~ ^/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/version\d*/(.*)$ /$1 last;
    }
    ....
}

Regards
